# How to call a seed in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Inside my seeds folder, I have another folder called products. Which contains a large number of seeds for various products.

How can I call each one from the Database Seeder?

I've tried this but to no avail:

```
 $this->call('/products/product_1.php');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure they can be autoloaded and pass the **class name**, not the path to the file. Since `app/database/seeds` is included in `composer.json` classmaps by default on Laravel, all files inside it can be autoloaded simply by using its name.

```
$this->call('Product1');
```

Oh, just remember to `composer dump-autoload` after creating a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I need to call seeds after some migration is executed (i.e. after admin table is created, there must be some admin in the table).

I use this in the end of `up` method.

```php
App::make('DatabaseSeeder')->call('UserTableSeeder');
```

This way, you can call migration from any point in your App.